# Can we export testcases/Reports from testlink to JIRA

Tags: jira, jira-plugin, jira-rest-api, jira-agile

We are planning to use one testcase management tool for our project.

I am using testlink in my previous project.

But my management want JIRA as all our sprint planning and bug tracking is happing over there.

Can I export Testlink testcases and reports in JIRA without using any add-ion

If no, Then what are other option I can use.

I have find Zephyr add-ion which can do similer like this.  is it any other option present?

I have also found that JIRA can accept rest-api but then I need to make changes in testlink project so testlink can send JSON to JIRA

What should I follow. any suggestion will help

Answer (score 1):

I worked with one QA team that created a custom 'testcase' issue type in JIRA. They removed all the standard JIRA fields that weren't required and added in custom fields for things that were not covered by standard JIRA fields (such as 'test category', 'pass/fail' checkbox, etc.).

The 'testcase' issues were used as sub-tasks for user stories. Using this approach each requirement had one or more test cases associated with it.

When they needed to report they would do an issue search for issues of type 'testcase' within a particular time period. Then they would export all fields to Excel.

Answer (score 1):

In my company we're using Testlink and JIRA and has been proposed to remove Testlink migrating all the data to JIRA but depending of the usage of JIRA(amount of data it is managing) as this can overload JIRA due to you will need several custom fields, maybe customized with JavaScript and that can be worth.

We analysed the possibility to use the [Zephyr](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.thed.zephyr.je/cloud/overview) plugin which is appropiated for this usage.